# Extract object data returned from API request with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

The returned object from the API call looks as follows with var_dump:

```
object(API\Resources\Address)#2526 (7) {
  ["city"]=>
  string(4) "city"
  ["country"]=>
  string(2) "US"
  ["phone"]=>
  NULL
  ["postal_code"]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  ["region"]=>
  string(2) "DE"
  ["street1"]=>
  string(10) "111 street"
  ["street2"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

can/should I get at my data with json_decode or somehow map it?  Or a foreach?

Need to pull out things like "postal_code" to echo.

Thanks in advance.

tried with json_decode but am getting critical error

Comment: It's an object, so you should be able to get the data from it with regular object properties, `->city`, `->country`, `->postal_code`

Comment: If it looks like that in a `var_dump`, then `json_decode` has (almost definitely) already been called

Comment: `json_decode()` is used to convert a JSON string to an object or array. This is already an object, you don't need to do anything special. The API has converted it to its own class, you should check the API documentation for the methods to interact with it.

Comment: But since the properties are public, you can just access them directly as @aynber said.

Comment: $object = $account_info->getAddress(); echo $object->postal_code; ?   And one problem with this API is lack of documentation. So I'm guessing how things work by diving into the method files.